# Changing alert priority which created by AWS ASG notification

Tags: amazon-web-services, opsgenie

I monitor instances by getting SNS notification when ASG scales.

Link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/ASGettingNotifications.html

Then, I route the alerts to SNS -> Opsgenie. Till here everything works perfectly fine.

My question is, I don't have any control over the "Priority" field in Opsgenie and all the alerts have the same priority (for example p3).
I have two AWS account (dev and prod) and I want to get alerts on dev account with LOW priority. on the other hand, I need to get alert with HIGH priority for prod account.

What's the best way to get around that and specify priorities based on either AWS accounts or SNS topics or even ASGs?

Thanks,

Comment: Using routing rules might be useful. Take a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0MBkfwevZOE&list=PLqRRY_KP21FuIIt36InZ5qZkbQrLl5uBL&index=14